# Can't run mapproxy server: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, wms, mapproxy

I have successfully installed a MapProxy == 1.8.0. And I have set `mapproxy-util create -t base-config gasps`
But when I run server, using `mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml`

Console throws it:

```
l
[2019-09-04 11:36:08,452] mapproxy.config - INFO - reading: /root/mapproxy/gasps/mapproxy.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mapproxy/bin/mapproxy-util", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/script/util.py", line 365, in main
    commands[command]['func'](args)
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/script/util.py", line 84, in serve_develop_command
    app = make_wsgi_app(mapproxy_conf, debug=options.debug)
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/wsgiapp.py", line 106, in make_wsgi_app
    services = conf.configured_services()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 209, in configured_services
    return self.services.services()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1479, in services
    new_services = creator(service_conf or {})
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1627, in demo_service
    layers[layer_name] = layer_conf.wms_layer()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/util/py.py", line 78, in wrapper
    cache[args] = func(self, *args)
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1326, in wms_layer
    from mapproxy.service.wms import WMSLayer
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/service/wms.py", line 36
    from mapproxy.util import async
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

asyncio is installed. How to solve a problem?

Comment: It was solved by installing mapproxy == 1.12.0

Comment: You may want to add this as an aswer and accept it so the question is closed and other people can refer to it in the future.